# Magento sub store always redirects to default store after magento setup:di:compile, did this completely delete my sub store?

Tags: magento2, multistore

I am using **Magento 2**.

I can still see the **sub store** in the **Magento backend** and it has a URL as **sample.example.com** while the main store URL is **example.com**. It was working fine, the sub store was loosely based on the main store. I created a module for the main store and was told to try to go into developer mode and then do `php magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: How do you have `sample.example.com` set up? How does it know to load the alternate store when you go there>

Comment: did this mean you want to delete sub store ? then logged in as admin then click on system - > All stores -> here listed all you sub store -> select which one you want to delete -> delete store -> after that run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command